# How to strictly limit the number of CloudKit results with resultsLimit

Tags: swift, cloudkit

Let me set up a scene for you: I have a CloudKit DB with 1000 records. And I need to fetch 150.

Problem #1: By default, CloudKit returns 100 records and a cursor. If I use that cursor to fetch the next batch, I'll end up fetching 200 records. And even that is not guaranteed, which brings us to,

Problem #2: The 100 records number is not fixed. CloudKit will decide how many records to return, depending on the current load of CloudKit's servers. So I can get, say, only 30 records on the first query and 30 more on the second query = 60.

Problem #3: If I fetch the next batch in a loop, I'll end up with all 1000 records.

Here is my looping code, just for the test I've set a `resultsLimit: 75`.

```
func fetchRecords() async throws -> [CKRecord] {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "MyRecordType", predicate: predicate)
        query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "datePublished", ascending: false)]
        
        var records: [CKRecord] = []
        var (matchResults, queryCursor) = try await CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.MyDB").publicCloudDatabase.records(matching: query, resultsLimit: 75)
        
        records.append(contentsOf: matchResults
                                    .compactMap { _, result in try? result.get()}
                                    .compactMap { $0 })

        while let cursor = queryCursor {
            (matchResults, queryCursor) = try await CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.MyDB").publicCloudDatabase.records(continuingMatchFrom: cursor, resultsLimit: 75)
            records.append(contentsOf: matchResults
                                        .compactMap { _, result in try? result.get()}
                                        .compactMap { $0 })
        }
        
        print("Will return \(records.count) CloudKit records")
        return records
    }
```

This method will return all 1000 records, fetching them by 75 / query.

Is there a way to strictly ask CloudKit to deliver 150 records (in batches or not, but no more than 150) or should I use the DB inefficiently and fetch as much as I can (like 200) from CloudKit, and manually pick 150 of them in Swift code afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `resultsLimit` is the maximum number of rows that CloudKit will return. Instead of hardcoding `75` as the `resultsLimit` in the `while` loop. Adjust that number based on how many more results you still need to obtain. And break out of the `while` loop once you reach the desired goal.

Let's say there is a variable named `maxRows` and it's set to 150 or any other desired number of rows.

```swift
while let cursor = queryCursor && records.count < maxRows {
    let limit = maxRows - results.count
    (matchResults, queryCursor) = try await CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.MyDB").publicCloudDatabase.records(continuingMatchFrom: cursor, resultsLimit: limit)
    records.append(contentsOf: matchResults
                                .compactMap { _, result in try? result.get()}
                                .compactMap { $0 })
}
```